# What is happening with the generator in Bendersky's TDOP implementation?

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow along with the Top-down Operator Precedence example from here:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/02/top-down-operator-precedence-parsing/

I can't follow the generator code. The code below does something with a generator (`token`, which returns functions):

```
t = token
token = next() # this affects t?
left = t.nud()
```

I would have though that I could change the order of the operations like below, but the code breaks in this case.

```
t = token
left = t.nud()
token = next()
```

It looks to me that the `next()` call shouldn't change `t` but it does. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` doesn't change `t`, but `t.nud()` will call `next()` internally and therefore changes the result of `token = next()`.